# Calling a python program using symfony process (PHP) by activating an anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I'd like to call a python script from my php webserver process, by using its anaconda environment.

Using the internet, I've assembled this command: `. $(conda info --base)/bin/activate env_name && python /path/to/myfile.py && conda deactivate`

- Note 1: not using `source` because the webserver executes in `sh` and `source` is a bash thing; it needs to be `.`
- Note 2: I'm using `$(conda info --base)/bin/activate` to automatically find the path to conda, instead of hardcoding it. It returns something like `/home/me/miniconda3`

Anyway: when I run this command in my shell, I get the output I want, the tool runs.

When I run it from the (apache linux) webserver, it fails.

My calling code:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

    $process = Process::fromShellCommandline($cmd);
    $process->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
    $process->setTimeout(0);
    $process->run();
```

The error I find in `$process->getErrorOutput()` indicates clearly that a required module in my python code is not found, as in, the environment has not been changed.

What could I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Aha. I did not test correctly myself. When explicitly using `sh` instead of my usual shell, I managed to try some more.

The solution is:

`. $(conda info --base)/bin/activate && conda activate env_name && python /path/to/myfile.py && conda deactivate`

As in:

- source the activate script
- activate the environment normally
- run python
- deactivate normally

I was under the false impression that sourcing the activate could already accept a parameter, but it appears to just ignore that.